# What is the best way for cahcing an irregular changing data - table in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, sqlcachedependency

I am a web developer on MVC 4 and want to use the cache concept to improve the speed of my home page.
My website is a portal for sports and I have a slider in my home page which show the online result of matches.
The match results data may change every 5 minutes, 10 minutes or 1 hour! Thus it seems to be better if I can cache the result according to table changes not by a fixed TimeDuration of OutputCache.

What is the best way to cache this result?

Thanks

Comment: I have read this article [sqldependecy-mvc](http://www.felinesoft.com/blog/index.php/2011/07/asynchronous-asp-net-mvc-and-sqldependency/).is it fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Article[SqlDependency with Entity Framework 5.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/496484/SqlDependency-with-Entity-Framework) has a brief description for caching in MVC with SQL Notification.